# No performance gained when changing the debug build mode to release build mode?

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, visual-c++, dll, release

I have implemented a c++ dll that has much heavy math computation, then used it in Unity3D engine. The problem is :

when I switched the dll build mode from "debug" to "release", the application gained no performance improvement at all!

But it did does sometimes ago, about 3 times faster than debug mode! Suddenly, somehow, the release mode bring no perfomance!

I compared the release configuration in project properties with a new empty c++ dll project, they seemed to be the same as each other.

So how could this happen?

Answer (score 0):

`Debug` and `Release` modes are not technically defined things in the c++ standard, your compiler has no obligation to actually make `Release` code any faster - and depending on the kind of thing your software is doing the difference might be quite minimal.

If you really need extra speed I would recommend maybe writing a compute shader, depending on your type of problem.

Comment: By "writing a compute shader", you mean put the computation on GPU instead of CPU?